# Produce result table trom multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have 3 tables contained data for 3 different types of events

Type1, Type2, Type3 with two columns:

```
DatePoint ValuePoint
```

I want to produce result table which would look like that:

```
DatePoint TotalType1 TotalType2 TotalType3
```

I've started from that

```
SELECT [DatePoint]
      ,SUM(ValuePoint) as TotalType1 
  FROM [dbo].[Type1]
  GROUP BY [DatePoint]
  ORDER BY [DatePoint]

SELECT [DatePoint]
      ,SUM(ValuePoint) as TotalType2
  FROM [dbo].[Type2]
  GROUP BY [DatePoint]
  ORDER BY [DatePoint]

SELECT [DatePoint]
      ,SUM(ValuePoint) as TotalType3
  FROM [dbo].[Type3]
  GROUP BY [DatePoint]
  ORDER BY [DatePoint]
```

So I have three result but I need to produce one (`Date TotalType1 TotalType2 TotalType3`), what I need to do next achieve my goal?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that `DatePoint` which is exists in one type may or may not exist in another

Comment: Within A table is DatePoint unique?

Comment: @BalamBalam no it is not unique in any of source tables but it will be unique in final output table

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take. I assume that you *don't* have the same datetime values in every table (certainly, the stuff I get to work with is never so consistant). There should be an easier way to do this, but once you're past two outer joins things can get pretty tricky.

```
SELECT
   dp.DatePoint
  ,isnull(t1.TotalType1, 0) TotalType1
  ,isnull(t2.TotalType2, 0) TotalType2
  ,isnull(t3.TotalType3, 0) TotalType3
 from (--  Without "ALL", UNION will filter out duplicates
       select DatePoint
        from Type1
       union select DatePoint
        from Type2
       union select DatePoint
        from Type3) dp
  left outer join (select DatePoint, sum(ValuePoint) TotalType1
                    from Type1
                    group by DatePoint) t1
   on t1.DatePoint = db.DatePoint
  left outer join (select DatePoint, sum(ValuePoint) TotalType2
                    from Type2
                    group by DatePoint) t2
   on t2.DatePoint = db.DatePoint
  left outer join (select DatePoint, sum(ValuePoint) TotalType3
                    from Type3
                    group by DatePoint) t3
   on t3.DatePoint = db.DatePoint
 order by dp.DatePoint
```

Comment: getting that error on lines `16`, `20` and `24`: `The multi-part identifier "db.DatePoint" could not be bound.` I've changed to  `dp' :)

Comment: Yes. (Minor typos are hard to catch when you can't test the code you've written...)

Comment: I am getting a bit different results(different summary values) from your and from @Li0li queries... you commented that SUMs need to be within the outer joins(c). Why? Is it affecting performance? +1 for `isnull` to you by the way.

Comment: Just checked a couple the sum values with excel, in your case they correct in case of @Li0li they are not correct.

Comment: Bit-size explanation (comments can't be long): if 4 tables, 1 master (M) and 3 subsets (ss#), with 2 rows in each subset for a "master" key value, then join M into ss1, you get 2 rows; then join that into ss2, and you get 4 rows (every key on left matched with each matching key on right); then join into ss3, and again, 4 rows in left match *each* with 2 the rows in right, to produce 8 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose some distinct could help, but the general idea should be the following:

```
SELECT
    t.[DatePoint],
    SUM(t1.ValuePoint) as TotalType1,
    SUM(t2.ValuePoint) as TotalType2,
    SUM(t3.ValuePoint) as TotalType3 
FROM
(
    SELECT [DatePoint] FROM [dbo].[Type1]
    UNION
    SELECT [DatePoint] FROM [dbo].[Type2]
    UNION
    SELECT [DatePoint] FROM [dbo].[Type3]
) as t

LEFT JOIN
    [dbo].[Type1] t1
ON
    t1.[DatePoint] = t.[DatePoint]
LEFT JOIN
    [dbo].[Type2] t2
ON
    t2.[DatePoint] = t.[DatePoint]
LEFT JOIN
    [dbo].[Type3] t3
ON
    t3.[DatePoint] = t.[DatePoint]
GROUP BY
    t.[DatePoint]
ORDER BY
    t.[DatePoint]
```

Comment: I like how your handling the DatePoint by unioning it together you avoid the mess of trying to collacese the datepoint

Comment: Very similar to mine, but the SUMs need to be within the outer joins. Hard to explain... try it with, say, 2 rows in each table for a given date, and the SUMs will be off (should show 8 each, if my logic is straight).

Comment: I agree with Philip.  Two matches on T1 will duplicate any matches in T2 or T3.  +1 Philip

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all of the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
    SQ.DatePoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SQ.type = 1 THEN SQ.ValuePoint ELSE 0 END) AS TotalType1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SQ.type = 2 THEN SQ.ValuePoint ELSE 0 END) AS TotalType2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SQ.type = 3 THEN SQ.ValuePoint ELSE 0 END) AS TotalType3
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS type,
        DatePoint,
        ValuePoint
    FROM
        dbo.Type1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS type,
        DatePoint,
        ValuePoint
    FROM
        dbo.Type2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS type,
        DatePoint,
        ValuePoint
    FROM
        dbo.Type3
    ) AS SQ
GROUP BY
    DatePoint
ORDER BY
    DatePoint
```

From the little information provided though, it seems like there are some flaws in the database design, which is probably part of the reason that querying the data is so difficult.

Comment: Basically all data comes from excel file, so thats why i need to query it this way to produce data in format i need, than this data will be using to build charts.

Comment: Did you test this query on your data?

Comment: Just tested and it is working well, looking to execution plan to compere with @Philip Kelley query

Comment: Couldnt figure out how to add counts there, trying to go like that `COUNT(CASE WHEN SQ.type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalType1Count`, etc... but getting wrong counts

Comment: than i've changed it to `SUM(CASE WHEN SQ.type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalType1Count` and it is working, what do you think is it would be right?

Comment: The `SUM` is effectively giving you `COUNT` here. A count is simply summing 1 for every row that matches what you're counting. That's what the code here does.